# systemd how to do immediately as first thing after init 0 or init 6

Tags: systemd

my `/etc/systemd/system/myshutdown.service` has

```
#!/bin/bash

[Unit]
Description=license administration shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
After=final.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/scripts/license_administration_shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=final.target
```

my `license_administration_shutdown.sh` performs a few `lmutil lmdown -force` to kill those corresponding ones that I had kicked off in `/root/scripts/license_administration.sh` and that corresponding systemd service.

My question is I want my shutdown script to happen immediately or as one of the very first things after an `init 6` of `init 0` is done, is my above systemd service syntax correct for making that happen?  My intent is to kill those lmgrd processes that I believe are causing *a stop job is running for session* warning that is a 1m30s inconvenient delay on shutdown/reboot.

Is there any more syntax to the above service that can be added or changed to give it more priority or ensure it happens as soon after `init 6` or `init 0` is done?

Comment: `final.target` "may be used to pull in late services after all normal services are already terminated" - I guess that's not what you want. Check `shutdown.target` and `reboot.target` in `man systemd.special`

Comment: You could also run `systemctl poweroff --no-block` to ignore blocking services.

Comment: can you tell me how I can make my service run on either `shutdown.target` or `reboot.target` as those seem more appropriate for me than using `final.target`... i need my script to run on either... reboot and shutdown are two completely different targets correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a service-stopping service, perhaps it would be best if you added an `ExecStopPost` action to your license manager service.

If the license manager uses default dependencies, then it will automatically have a conflict with shutdown.target. If it doesn't use default dependencies, you can add the `Conflicts=shutdown.target` into your license manager's service description.

When the system goes to shutdown or reboot, it does so by invoking the shutdown.target which (mostly) automatically conflicts with every running service. Your license manager service will be stopped, and as a part of that it will run the command(s) specified by `ExecStopPost=`.